# Send A Product as a gift

Tags: magento-1.9

Can we give a privilege for the customer to send surprise gifts on a particular day to the person to whom a customer want to?

Answer (score 1):

In default magento, you can allow customers to select whether the order is a gift or not (http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/gift-options.html). But no default option to deliver the order on a selected date as it will really depends on how long the courier service will take to deliver the item :).

You can ask you customers for a date which the need the order to get delivered and then based on the performance of your courier partner you can decide when to ship that order.

You can try installing the free module https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/delivery-date-delivery-time.html

Comment: How can allow customers to select whether the order is a gift or not?

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/gift-options.html

Comment: if this helps, accept as asnwer.

Comment: this is not working properly in backend/admin panel.

Comment: What you mean by not working on backend/admin panel.